# Wanting to setup a desktop to be accessed via a laptop for its processing power

Tags: networking, remote-access

As per the title, I'm currently building a desktop which far exceeds the capacity of my laptop, but I would like to access said desktop with the laptop. When I say access I'm speaking in terms of say... running a visually intense game which the laptop would not be capable of doing.

I do have software like team viewer, but this results in massive input lag - my question is what is the best way to implement what I'm looking to do?

Virtual server? Adding an additional HD for sole access of the laptop? Just some ideas I had....

Also this will be accessed from within the home but likely different rooms etc. Never more than say 20m away.

Comment: So you want to be able to use the desktop's hardware-accelerated graphics but display the image on the laptop's screen? If you didn't need that, this would be easy; it's what Remote Desktop does all the time on Windows, and similar setups exist for other OSes as well.

Comment: What you want cannot be easily accomplished with a universal solution. Game streaming is possible, however. [Steam should currently have this in beta.](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2092220/hands-on-steams-in-home-pc-game-streaming-beta-already-feels-like-magic.html)